# React js socket io emit

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io, chat

im building a chat app with mern and socket.io, i tried to emit with callback but it emit function not value and when i delete setList(l=>[...l,data]) it emit (first problem).
And the second problem, when i recieve the message and push it to list twice (useEffect).

**Client side:**

```
import React,{ useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

function Room(props) {
    const [message,setMessage]=useState('');
    const [list, setList] = useState([]);
    const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:5000";
    const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT, {
        credentials: true
      });

    const sendMessage=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault(); 
        let data=message;
        //the first problem is here
    socket.emit('send',(data)=>{
        setList(l=>[...l,message])
    });
               
        
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        //the second problem is here
        socket.on('rec',(data)=>{
           setList(l=>[...l,data])           
        })
    },[])

  return (
    <div>
        <div>
            {list!==[] && list!==null && list.map((el,i)=>{
                return <p key={i}>{el}</p>
            })}
        </div>
        <div>
            <form>
                <input value={message} onChange={e=>setMessage(e.target.value)} />
                <button onClick={sendMessage}>Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Room;
```

**Server Side:**

```
const io = new Server(server, { cors: { origin: '*'}});
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    next();
})
dotenv.config();

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.emit('greeting', {
        greeting: 'Hello Client'
    })
  
    socket.on("send", (data) => {
        io.emit("rec", data);
        console.log(data)
      });
  });
  

server.listen(process.env.PORT, err => err?console.log('server error'):console.log(`server is running on PORT ${process.env.PORT}`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 

```
//the first problem is here
    socket.emit('send',(data)=>{
        setList(l=>[...l,message])
    });
```

has to be

```
 socket.emit('send', message, (data)=>{
        setList(l=>[...l,message])
    });
```

(you missed the argument, see https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#socketemiteventname-args)

2)

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        //the second problem is here
        socket.on('rec',(data)=>{
           setList(l=>[...l,data])           
        })
    },[])
```

it's not really a problem, because you add the same message here and in sendMessage, by using setList twice. I suppose for the chat app you need to change `io.emit("rec", data);` with a different response.